# SQL concat rows table2 into column table1

Tags: mysql, left-join, concatenation

```
Table1
+----+--------------+
| id |   csvalues   |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |    100;1001; |
|  3 |    300;12;   |
|  4 |    400;44;   |
+----+--------------+


Table2
+----+----------+--------+
| id | csvalues2|table1ID|
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |  10      |    1   |
|  3 |  30      |    1   |
|  4 |   111    |    3   |
+----+----------+--------+
```

There are these 2 tables.
I wan't to get a result like this

```
RESULT
+----+----------------+
| id |   csvalues     |
+----+----------------+
|  1 |100;1001;10;30; |
|  3 |300;12;111;     |
+----+----------------+
```

Is it possible? I tried to Left Join the tables but can't get the Table2.csvalues2 into RESULT.csvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution that will work with your example data. I used an inner join instead of a left join because your example implies that you only want to include rows from Table1 that have related rows in Table2:

```
select Table1.id,
  concat(Table1.csvalues,group_concat(Table2.csvalues2 separator ';'),';') as csvalues
from Table1
  inner join Table2 on Table2.table1ID = Table1.id
group by Table1.id;
```

Comment: Actually your solution doesn't work correctly either :-) The ";" separating the output from Table1 and Table2 is in the wrong place.

Comment: I upvoted you anyway because your answer was "even more correct" than mine :-D

Comment: Normally I would put a separator in between the output from Table1 and Table2, but in this sample data set there is already a trailing semi-colon in the data form Table1 so that's unnecessary. And the sample output also has a trailing semi-colon, so that's why I added it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to do something like

```
SELECT Table1.ID, CONCAT(Table1.csvalues, ';', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Table2.csvalues2 SEPARATOR ';') FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.table1ID = Table1.ID)) FROM Table1;
```

In a test database I put together quicky this returned the result you expected.

Comment: This won't quite match the OP's desired output. It will return a 3rd row with id=4, csvalues=NULL.